# Microsoft.Sharepoint(2019) Code to Update Calander Event Throws COM exception saying Message - "Cannot complete this action.Please try again"

Tags: 2019

The update internal method inside Microsoft.SharePoint throws the above mentioned error while adding/updating events in the calendar list in SharePoint 19 Server.
The same code work in case of SharePoint 13, 16. Also the events are successfylly added/updated using SharePoint ClientContext.

Please help.

Comment: Can you please provide a code sample where the error is thrown?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer for my exception. 
I was trying to update every property of the item associated with the event. When "Geolocation" property of item was set to empty string, The particular exception was thrown.

However, the exception is a type of generic. Microsoft.SharePoint may throw same message for other exceptions